# Questions regarding case matching in scala statement case List(a) => true

Tags: scala

Can you please explain the second case in this function which detects palindromes.

```
def isListPanlindrome(list: List[Int]): Boolean = list match {
  case Nil => true
  case List(a) => true
  case list => (list.head == list.last && isListPanlindrome(list.tail.init))
}
```

Specific questions that I've are :

1. What is `a` here, it's not even defined anywhere.
2. How is the case matching working with an instance of List object.
3. Why is it able to match a list with a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is a here, it's not even defined anywhere.

It is being defined exactly right there.
`case List(a) => true` means: match a **List** of just one element, and call that element `a`. Since it is not used anywhere, you may just do `case List(_) => true`.
However, IMHO, it would be more idiomatic *(and maybe even more performant)* to do `case _ :: Nil => true`

> 2. How is the case matching working with an instance of List object.
> 3. Why is it able to match a list with a single element

It is basically calling the `unapply` method in the **companion objet** `List`. This is called [**extractor objects**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).
*(I believe the linked article provides an excellent explanation of how it works, so I won't go further)*

Comment: Along the lines of your point in #1, the third case can also be simplified to 
`case _ => <expression>` since that `list` just shadows the `list` in the function arguments